# Multithreading in Python/BeautifulSoup scraping

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup

Hi i went to scaping same data from website.
But when i went to use Multithreading  i have error 
This is my code

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  # This is a thread-based Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

def crawlToCSV(url):
    print(url)
#    req = requests.get(url)
#    detail = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
#    images=[]
#    for img in detail.find_all("img"):
#        images.append(img["src"])
#
#    return images
    return "k"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    FILE_LINES = 10000000
    NUM_WORKERS = cpu_count() * 2
    chunksize = FILE_LINES // NUM_WORKERS * 4   # Try to get a good chunksize. You're probably going to have to tweak this, though. Try smaller and lower values and see how performance changes.
    pool = Pool(NUM_WORKERS)
    req = requests.get('https://m.web.com/list?cg=1000')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
    i=0
    for a in soup.find_all("a"):        
        if "ad?id" not in a["href"]:
            continue
        i=i+1
        if i==3 :
            break
        url=a["href"]
        print(url)
        results = pool.map(crawlToCSV, url)
    with open("Output.csv", "ab") as f:
        writeFile = csv.writer(f)
        for result in results: 
            writeFile.writerow(result)
```

But in my console i have this [image]

How i can get url in crawlToCSV without \n between char

Comment: I cannot reproduce the script. I copied the code, added `import requests` to the top, and get `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='m.web.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /list?cg=1000 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E399799AC8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))` error message. I don't think this is an mcve question

Comment: i have changed name of website and i have import requests in my code

Comment: well with the code you posted I cannot reproduce the error, so I cannot help more than to suggest a *possible* solution. It looks like your code thinks it is handing each worker a letter instead of your desired URL. Maybe try storing the URL as a list with a single string containing the URL. That way when it attempts to iterate by items, each item will be an URL instead of a letter from one.

Comment: Yes thank you i have use list and in the function i use req = requests.get(url[:]) to get all url !! but its work  thank you